# Meteor: How can I use Spacebars to apply different CSS elements?

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, spacebars

I'd like to use a different color for the header of my card. I thought that I could use `Spacebars` unique `{{if` condition for it but it seems it only works with boolean variables and not with a condition that is checking for a string:

Here's my code:

```
{{#if type='ToDo'}}
    <div class="paper-card-header teal-header">
{{else}}
        {{#if type='Info'}}
            <div class="paper-card-header orange-header">
        {{else}}
            <div class="paper-card-header pink-header">
        {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

I'd like to use the CSS element of `teal-header` for the condition that `type==='ToDo'`, `orange-header` for the condition that `type==='Info' and`pink-header`for every other value of`type`.

How can I achieve this or is it not possible to do within Meteor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a helper to return the appropriate class:

```
Template.YOURTEMPLATE.helpers({
  headerClass: function () {
    var class = {
      'ToDo': 'teal-header',
      'Info': 'orange-header'
    }[this.type]
    return class || 'pink-header'
  }
})
```

Then in your template:

```
<div class="paper-card-header {{headerClass}}"></div>
```

Note that you *can* also use [Spacebars subexpressions](https://quip.com/RXFlAk9Rc2xI) with an equals helper like below, but I don't think that's the right option for this situation where there are multiple possibilities:

```
Template.registerHelper('equal', (x, y) => x === y)

<div class="paper-card-header {{#if (equal type "Info")}}orange-header{{/if}}"></div>
```

Having a general *equal* helpers is often very useful anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a helper and put it inside the 'class' attribute

```
<div class="paper-card-header {{getColorByType}}-header">
```

And in your template's javascript, something like

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  getColorByType(){
    var type = ... // get your type from the template instance

    if (type === 'ToDo'){
       return 'teal';
    } else if (type === 'Info'){
       return 'orange';
    }
    return 'teal';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers by @richsilv and @mati-o I've used template helpers as suggested by both of them. But I selected for what I personally think is an easier to read code (which gives me also the option to get even more different colors in):

```
Template.puzzle.helpers({
    headerColor: function () {
        switch (this.type) {
            case "ToDo":
                return 'md-orange-header';
            break;
            case "Info":
                return 'md-green-header';
            break;
            case "NewTG":
                return 'md-teal-header';
            break;
            default:
                return 'md-green-footer';
        }
    }
});
```

The use of this helper in the html code is the same but for completeness here's also that piece of code:

```
<div class="paper-card-header {{headerColor}}">
```

Thanks again to both for helping me out!